# is there a efficient way to detect object in image?

Tags: python, geometry

I am dealing with image data, which size is 1920*1080, and background color is white(250,250,250)
It has an object(one per image), which color is not white(in all cases)
Clearly, checking all pixels will be able to find coordinates of bounding box, but its speed is very slow due to image size.

Is there an efficient way to detect object in such tasks?

Comment: there is probably an efficient way ... it would depend on the number of pixels the object covers ... please add info about the object

Comment: @jsotola yes, there is an efficient way. If we do not know the size and shape of the object, then we can repeatedly divide the screen to four smaller rectangles. If the object has a fair size, then this will find it earlier, especially if the object is convex.

Comment: This can be done using pillow's [`Image.getbbox()`](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/Image.html#PIL.Image.Image.getbbox) method, though you'll need to modify the image so the background is black (also easily done in Pillow)

Comment: @kindall While an already implemented solution may work, I think it is important to understand how this can be solved. I think an efficient way if to always check the middle pixel and consider "upper left", "upper right", "lower left" and "lower right" to that pixel in the rectangle to be four sub-rectangles to be checked. Since this approach quickly reduces available convex shapes, the bigger and more convex your object is, the quicker the algorithm finds it.

Comment: if you want to know how to do it then go look at the Pillow source.  :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It largely depends on your object. If your object is a single pixel and you have no information whatsoever about its location, then you will need to process each pixel in some order on your screen until you find it. However, if the object fills the screen, then you will find it at any index you look upon first.

Assuming that we do not know anything about the object's shape or size and that after finding a pixel of the object we need to find out its shape and assuming further that the object is continuous, you will need to do the following for maximal efficiency

## Repeatedly divide your problem-space by four until you find a non-white pixel

Look into the algorithm called [divide and conquer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divide-and-conquer_algorithm), or, its Latin name, divide et impera. The idea is to divide your task to similar but smaller subtasks. In this case it would consist in checking the very middle pixel of your rectangle. That will either be non-white, which is the end sign, or, if not, you will have four smaller rectangles:

- upper-left
- upper-right
- lower-right
- lower-left

Repeat the process. It is advisable to perform this in a level-first manner because if your object has a larger size, then this approach will likely yield the correct result earlier.

## We found an object! How to determine its shape?

We assumed that it's continuous

So, You will need to find out what the color of the adjacent pixels are and then store the current pixel as already visited. Repeat the process for the similarly colored pixels, with almost the same logic, but with the addition of ignoring pixels that were already processed, until there are no more pixels to process.

EDIT

**Colored Pixel**: A pixel which takes part of the object we are searching for. At first, the object may be anywhere on the screen, we do not know its size or shape, but we assumed that it's continuous.

We are searching the first "colored pixel" (pixel which is part of the object) with the approach of divide et impera, dividing the rectangle into four sub-rectangles, until the first colored pixel is found:

```
r <- rectange(x1, y1, x2, y2) //0, 0, 1920, 1080
q <- queue(r) // a queue that consists of a single element at this point, which is r
cp <- null
while ((not queue.empty()) or (cp is null)) do
    r <- queue.pop()
    c <- r.center()
    if (c.isColored()) then cp <- c
    else if ((r.x1 < r.x2) and (r.y1 < r.y2)) then
        q.push(r.x1, r.y1, c.x - 1, c.y)
        q.push(c.x, r.y1, r.x2, c.y - 1)
        q.push(r.x1, c.y + 1, c.x, r.x2)
        q.push(c.x + 1, c.y, r.x2, r.y2)
end while
```

So, we repeatedly deconstruct the problem into similar but smaller sub-problems.

Now, let's assume that the algorithm above has found the very first known colored pixel, called cp, that's part of the object. Since at this point we only know the location of a single pixel of the object, but we do not know the size of the object, nor its shape of the object and we also do not know in which section is this pixel located inside the object. But we know that the object is continuous, otherwise we would be speaking about multiple objects.

The fact that this is continuous means that all pixels of the object (that I called "colored pixels") can be reached by a finite number (0 or more) steps starting from the colored pixel that we have found, where each of our steps consists of a change of focus from a pixel that's part of the object towards a pixel that is also part of the object.

For this purpose we need to store all the pixels that we have found so far and repeatedly find new adjacent colored pixels until there is nothing new to be added. So, assuming that cp is the colored pixel we have already found, we could apply something like this:

```
c <- collection(cp) //the collection of pixels that are detected to be part of the object, at the start there is a single pixel found to match this criteria
q <- queue(cp) //queue of pixels to be processed in terms of finding adjacent pixels. Since we are only aware of cp at this point, we have a single element that is to be part of the queue at this stage

    while (not q.empty()) do
        cp <- q.pop()
        if (not c.contains(cp)) then c.add(cp)
        A <- cp.adjacent()
        for a in A do
            if ((a.isColored) and (not c.contains(a))) then q.push(a)
        end for
    end while
```